# Create a 3X2 Grid that each cell is square-shaped using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin.Forms. Now I need to design a grid in my page and the grid is 3X2 (2 rows, 3 columns). But I need all the cells in this grid square-shaped and the width of this grid matches its parent view.

In another word, suppose the width of the screen(or the parent view of this grid) is 3, so the width of each column is 1. How can I force the Height of each row to be exactly 1 (so that each cell of the grid the height equals the width)?

Here is my design but not work:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Is there a pure XAML solution to this issue?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4):

`Star` sizing adjust itself with available space by orientation, so you need to adjust by hand via overriding `OnSizeAllocated` method(be careful nested method calling when resizing child).

**Xaml:**

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

**Xaml.cs**

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

    if (3 * height > 2 * height)
        mainGrid.HeightRequest = 2.0 / 3 * width;
    else
        mainGrid.WidthRequest = 3.0 / 2 * height;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I am a little confused about `if (3 * height > 2 * height)`

Comment: Lets explain with an example: if we assume each square edge would be 1", your container with should be 3" and height 2".  Your `Grid` should respect this 3x2 scale.  That condition checks if we reduce `Width` or `Height`.

Comment: @eakgul - presumably you meant **3 * width** - comparing `height` to `height` is not sensible - hence Alan's confusion.

Comment: ... or maybe its the second `height` that should be `width`. Anyone who uses this should test different situations both ways...  Clearer test would be `if (width / 3 > height / 2)`. And I have no idea whether the formulas after that are correct.  Good example of code that **needs comment explaining the algorithm**.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

    double colsCount = MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;
    double rowsCount = MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Count;
    if (colsCount > 0 & rowsCount > 0)
    {
        MainGrid.HeightRequest = width / colsCount * rowsCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this assumes in XAML: `<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" ...`  Also, why are  colsCount & rowsCount `double` rather than `int`? You wanted to make sure the division didn't truncate?

Comment: This did not work for me. Height was bigger than Width a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Calculate the height of a Grid containing square cells
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        if (_grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count == 0 || _grid.RowDefinitions.Count == 0)
            return;

        var totalColSpacing = (_grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1) * _grid.ColumnSpacing;
        var totalRowSpacing = (_grid.RowDefinitions.Count - 1) * _grid.RowSpacing;

        var cellWidth = (width - totalColSpacing) / _grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;

        _grid.HeightRequest = (cellWidth * _grid.RowDefinitions.Count) + totalRowSpacing;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a much easier way to do this. The trick is to name the first cell, and retrieve its width.

**Layout definition first:**

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="firstCell" />

  <!-- Further declaration of elements inside the grid... -->
</Grid>
```

**Then:** *(accounting for rowspacing, plus deducting 1 x [RowSpacing] because cells in the last row don't have rowspacing below themselves.)*

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

    int colCount = mainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;
    int rowCount = mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Count;

    if (colCount > 0 && rowCount > 0)
    {
        mainGrid.HeightRequest = (firstCell.Width + mainGrid.RowSpacing) * rowCount - mainGrid.RowSpacing;
    }
}
```